# Sort icon visible after refresh in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have added refresh button in jqgrid as shown below.

```
 grid.jqGrid('navGrid', "#divPager", {
        refresh: true
}
```

Once I performed column sorting and clicked on this refresh it wont hide sort icon and it wont clear sorting as well. I am using server side sorting.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to guess what is going wrong in your code (please share complete source code while asking questions) but here is a workaround to manually code for reload/refresh button.

`grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#divPager', {
    refresh: false
 }).navButtonAdd('#gridId', {
    id : "reload_grid",
    caption : "",
    title : "reload",
    buttonicon : "ui-icon-refresh",
    onClickButton : function (){
        grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
});`

And grid param `loadonce` should be `false` in your scenario.

Comment: I tried the same but not working. My issue is like once I sorted a column and clicked on refresh the sort icon still persisting.